# Bash exec write output to logfile and write PID to seperate file

Tags: bash, file, logging, exec, pid

I got a problem in the understanding of BASH, writing the output of exec command to a logfile & write the PID to a seperate file.
That's what I tried so far:

```
exec ./node -connect-manager -manager-address $MANAGER_IP:5998 -manager-web $MANAGER_IP:8000 >> /var/log/skywirenode.log >> echo $$ > /home/odrod420/skywireScript/node.pid &
```

Has anybody got an idea on what I am thinking wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do multiple redirections of `stdout` in a single statement. The `echo` statement should be done as a separate statement:

```
echo $$ > /home/odrod420/skywireScript/node.pid
exec ./node -connect-manager -manager-address $MANAGER_IP:5998 -manager-web $MANAGER_IP:8000 >> /var/log/skywirenode.log 2>&1
```

If you want to run `node` in the background and save its PID in the file, you shouldn't use `exec`, you should put `&` after the command, and echo `$!` to the file:

```
./node -connect-manager -manager-address $MANAGER_IP:5998 -manager-web $MANAGER_IP:8000 >> /var/log/skywirenode.log 2>&1 &
echo $! > /home/odrod420/skywireScript/node.pid
```

Comment: Maybe my approach was totally wrong, but with the "echo $$", I want to forward the PID of "./node" to a seperate file

Comment: @McJohnson The pid of `./node` will be `$$` because you `exec` it

Comment: @McJohnson I've updated the answer to show how to run `./node` in the background and save its PID in the file.

Comment: and you might also want to redirect stderr to the log file: `cmd >log 2>&1` or `cmd &>log`